# How to retrieve array of dictionary data in a html table?

Tags: python, flask

First of all, I am new at Python(flask) and programming in general. So... here I am. To keep learning from big mistakes.

I need to retrieve the data of an array of dictionaries to an HTML table. The Array contains Dictionaries of reservations. Each reservation (dictionary) have the keys 'day', 'time', 'courttype', 'name' and 'phone'.
Then I need to check the 'day', 'hour' and 'courttype' and print the 'name' on the specific timetable row/column of the table.

**UT2_Tasca.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

# Array of reservations
reservas = []

# Function to create reservation (dict) and store in array
def crearReserva(reqdia, reqhora, reqtipopista, reqnom, reqtelefon):

    reserva = { 'dia': reqdia, 'hora': reqhora, 'tipopista': reqtipopista, 'nom': reqnom,   'telefon': reqtelefon}
 
    reservas.append(reserva)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    global reservas
    return render_template('UT2_exemple4_registre.html')

@app.route('/formulari', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def formulari():
    return render_template('UT2_exemple4_registre.html')

@app.route('/reserves', methods=['GET','POST'])
def reserves():

    global reservas
    # array of title (weekday and hours) that will appear in the table headings
    titleColumn = ['','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']
    titleRow = ['15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00']

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # get data from form (request)
        reqdia = request.form['dia']
        reqhora = request.form['hora']
        reqtipopista = request.form['tipopista']
        reqnom = request.form['nom']
        reqtelefon = request.form['telefon']
        
        crearReserva (reqdia, reqhora, reqtipopista, reqnom, reqtelefon)

    else:
        return render_template('UT2_exemple4_reserves.html', reservas=reservas, row=titleRow, col=titleColumn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**
UT2exemple4_reserves.html**

```
...
<div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            {% for c in col %} <!-- prints columns heading of table -->
            <th>{{c}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for f in row %} <!-- prints rows heading of table -->
              <tr>
                <th>{{f}}</th>
                {% for res in reservas %}  
                <td> HERE I'D LIKE TO PRINT THE NAME OF THE PERSON THAT HAS MADE THE RESERVATION. BUT FIRST, SOMEHOW, I NEED TO CHECK/READ THE DAY, HOUR AND COURTTYPE AND THEN PRINT THE NAME... NOT SURE IF THAT IS POSIBLE ON HTML...</td>
                {% endfor %}
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
...
```

So... my logic is:

{% for res in reservas %} here I get one reservation as res

Then, somehow I need to check the day, hour and courttype of this reservation, and print the name in the specific time and day of the table...

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a grouped structure consisting of two nested dictionaries that represent the two axes of the table.
The first dictionary contains the times used as a key and dictionaries as a value.
The respective nested dictionary contains the days used as a key and a list of all entries that match this hour-day pair.

An output of the data would look like this.

```
{
  '15:00': {
    'Monday': [
      { 
        'hour':'15:00', 
        'day':'Monday', 
        'name': 'Mary'
      }
    ]
  }
  '16:00': { 
    'Wednesday': [
      { 
        'hour':'16:00', 
        'day':'Wednesday', 
        'name': 'John'
      }, 
      { 
        'hour':'16:00', 
        'day':'Wednesday', 
        'name': 'Tim'
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is the related code using a subclass of dict, the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which uses a factory function to provide missing values.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    { 'hour': '15:00', 'day': 'Monday',  'name': 'Mary' }, 
    { 'hour': '16:00', 'day': 'Wednesday', 'name': 'John' }, 
    { 'hour': '16:00', 'day': 'Wednesday', 'name': 'Tim' }, 
    { 'hour': '20:00', 'day': 'Thursday', 'name': 'Walter' }
]

@app.route('/timetable')
def timetable():
    res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    for item in data: 
        res[item['hour']][item['day']].append(item)

    cols = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']
    rows = ['15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00']

    return render_template('timetable.html', **locals())
```

Within the template you can now iterate over the rows and columns to create a table. If your structure contains entries for the respective hour-day pair, you can request their names and add them to the table cell separated by commas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Timetable</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Hour/Day</th>
                {% for col in cols -%}
                <th scope="col">{{ col }}</th>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in rows -%}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ row }}</th>
                {% for col in cols -%}
                <td>
                    {{ res[row][col] | map(attribute='name') | join(', ') }}
                </td>
                {% endfor -%}
            </tr>
            {% endfor -%}
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```